# are there any compatibility problems with Visual 2019 Preview?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am programming with the .Net Framework and I would like to download the Visual 2019 Preview Version, are there any Problems with my Visual 2017 Main Program?
thanks for your time :)

Comment: You might want to provide more detail as to why you are asking this question.  Problems you are having, etc.

Comment: I think AppleTree did. They're interested in trialing the Visual Studio 2019 preview and want to know how stable it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use Visual Studio 2017 for studying by using the .Net Framework (c#) and I downloaded the 2019 Preview and its pretty good so far, if you will use it for work I would recommended you to stay on the latest Version of the 2017 Edition but you can install the Preview and use Visual Studio 2017 without any problems at the same time, Microsoft also says: "Install the Preview right alongside your main release, leaving your production install undisturbed." you can read everything important also here:[Preview](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/)